# Why geofence check all user-layer permission in every wfs transaction request?

Tags: wfs-t, geoserver-geofence

We have more than thousand layer in geoserver and about hundred user in stand alone geofence.

We noticed something strange while editing feature by WFS transaction and that is that when we look at the postgresql logs, we find that geofence execute a number of `SELECT` query for all layers in geoserver. That means that geofence execute more than 1000 query for authorizing user for every wfs-t And that has slowed us down a lot. While we are editing one layer and the logical way is that geofence just check user permission on that layer. Not all layer in geoserver.

Is this really the behavior that happens in geofence?
Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Possibly because each WFS request is stateless.

Comment: how are your rules set up?

Comment: @nmtoken Hmmm...Could you explain more

Comment: @lan Turton There are more than 34000 rule for this thousand layer. But the user that I use for wfs-t has one `*` rule. It means that he has permission to all layer

Comment: In a WFS, the server doesn't maintain session state, so each request is regarded on it's own merit and must be authenticated (if required)

Comment: WFS-T transaction is stateless but if the request hits only one feature type then checking the rights for all the feature types does feel suboptimal.